# HTML.DropDownListFor - Syntactic Sugar for SelectList

Tags: vb.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using `Html.DropDownListFor` to build a select list. It is a simple list of numbers from 1 to 100. One of the parameters - `selectList As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)` - is the list's options, which I have usually built manually, like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.Sorting.IsAscending, _ 
 New SelectList(New Dictionary(Of String, Boolean) From _
 {{"Sort Ascending", True}, {"Sort Descending", False}}, "value", "key"))
```

Or from an enum, like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.Sorting.SortFieldCurrent, _
 New SelectList(Model.Sorting.SortFields, "value", "key"))
```

But this time I want a list from 1 to 100. And I refuse to manually create it :)

Is there some sweet LINQ magic to build a list for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Enumerable.Range` to generate the range of numbers:

C#:

```
IEnumerable<int> range = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
```

VB (Courtesy http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/):

```
Dim range As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx